# How to print last last two decimals into whole int

Tags: java, if-statement

My professor provided practice problem at the end of the lecture. At the end of the lecture he wanted us to print code where the users input is to be displayed like this in the console.

EX: User input : 105.25

What he wants shown in console: 25

Attached below is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lab07 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        double input;
        System.out.printf("Please enter a number: ");
        input = in.nextDouble();
        
        if (input < 0) {
            System.out.print("Negative value-exiting");
            System.exit(0);
            
        } else if (input > 10000) {
            System.out.print("Too much value-exiting");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            
            System.out.printf(input * 100);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should include your code as text in the question, not a screenshot.
When editing your question, have a look at the Markdown Editing Help (question-mark icon) in the Stack Overflow interface and learn how to format code in questions, if you don't already know how to do that.

Comment: @ScottLeis Sorry! fixed it.

Comment: What if the user input is 1234.5? What if it's 1.2345? Or 12345?

Comment: @marcosvaldez81
Do you need to print only the last two decimal places or all places after decimal?
Should we print 0 if there are no digits after the decimal?
The formal problem statement(as given by your professor) will be appreciated.
Don't worry about the question you asked, we will help you edit it.

Comment: It would be easier to solve this problem if you consider taking input as a `char` array.

Comment: @PalLaden We only need 2 numbers after the decimal place. So like if someone inputted .25 as their number in the console, professor wants the console to return 25. Another example is 125.32 --> 32. Thank you I hardly ask questions on here so sorry for my mistakes.

Comment: If the input is 9.876, will the output be 87 or 76?

Comment: Thank you Pal Laden. I really appreciate you for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will either need :

**For two digits after decimal point**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab07 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double input;
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        input = in.nextDouble();
        input *= 10;
        System.out.print((int)input%10);
        input *= 10;
        System.out.print((int)input%10);
    }

}
```

---

OR

**For last two digits after decimal**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab07 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        double input;
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        input = in.nextDouble();
        char[] i = (Double.valueOf(input)).toString().toCharArray();
        System.out.print(i[i.length-2]+" "+i[i.length-1]);
    }

}
```

---

Comment: Thank you Pal Laden.